# How do i input holidays into statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima, economics, python-holidays

Many thanks in advance. I've been looking to implement some seasonal decomposition for my analysis and was trying to use the X13 wrapper provided by statsmodel to run it. However, as I am running my seasonal decomposition on data from countries outside of the US, I was hoping to have some adjustments made to fit the holidays from other countries (e.g. Idul Fitri for Indonesia). How do I input this?

*I do note that the underlying x13 program provided by the US Census has a 'Genhol' function which allows users to essentially create a holiday spec file for customized holidays if running the X13 program on other countries. But I can't seem to find any information on running this within python.

Thanks in advance all :)